# Why use a different C library?

Tags: c, glibc, libc

I was looking into using Apple's Blocks runtime with clang on Linux, and I uncovered the [incompatibility issues](http://www.sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11157) with the GNU libc's `<unistd.h>`. Looking around a bit for more information I found one user [suggesting](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/libdispatch-dev/2010-June.txt):

> Oh well time to use a different libc?  I hear FreeBSD has a nice one!  :-)

As seemingly implied, this is a rather silly reason to use a different `libc`. But that did make me think:

Why *would* you ever swap your C library? Are there advantages/disadvantages to using one over the other (e.g. GNU libc vs. FreeBSD libc)? (I suppose this also applies to `libstdc++` vs. `libc++`).

Comment: Sometimes they have a target niche. For example, [Newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) is targeted for embedded systems, and is designed to be light and easy to port.

Comment: One situation that comes to my mind is cross-compiling for a different platform.

Comment: Also, the website for [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) actually lists some reasons why they (LLVM) decided to implement their own instead of using an existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three reasons off the top of my head.

1. **Legacy Reasons**: You have code written against the old [Rogue Wave](http://stdcxx.apache.org/),
2. **Size**: There's [musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/) and [dietlibc](http://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/),
3. To **Perform Android Cross Compile** using [Bionic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionic_%28software%29)